Include an icon in a DT table button (Buttons extension)
I'd like to have some icons in the buttons of a DT table. I mean the buttons created with the 'Buttons' extension.
library(DT)

dat <- iris

dtable <- datatable(
    dat,
    rownames = TRUE,
    extensions = "Buttons",
    options = 
        list(
            dom = "Bfrtip",
            buttons = list("copy", "csv")
        )
    )

How to add some icons in the buttons?

Change text by image or icon is also possible without fontawesome
          buttons = list(
          list(extend = "print", text = as.character(tags$img(src = "icons/Print.svg",alt = "Print")),
          list(extend = "csv", text =  as.character(tags$img(src = "icons/Download.svg",alt = "Download")))

For modify the text in pagination part, I add other option :
language = list(
            paginate = list(first="", last="",
                           `next` = as.character(tags$img(src = "icons/Forward.svg")), 
                            previous=as.character(tags$img(src = "icons/Backward.svg"))
                          )
          )

The complete datatable :
dtable <- datatable(
 dat,
 rownames = TRUE,
 extensions = "Buttons",
 options = list(
         dom = "Bfrtip",
         buttons = list(
          list(extend = "print", text = as.character(tags$img(src = "icons/Print.svg",alt = "Print")),
          list(extend = "csv", text =  as.character(tags$img(src = "icons/Download.svg",alt = "Download")))
                   ),
         language = list(
                paginate = list(first="", last="",`next` = as.character(tags$img(src = "icons/Forward.svg")),previous=as.character(tags$img(src = "icons/Backward.svg")) )
         )
 )


Good (+1). One just has to find the SVG icons

To have full control of a button, you have to use a list with the field extend to specify which button you want (copy, csv, ...), and then in this list you can include some other fields to set some options.
In particular you have the field text to set the text of the button, and HTML is allowed in this field.
So you can use for example the R package fontawesome and its fa_i function to include an icon. Here is an example:
library(DT)
library(fontawesome)

dat <- iris

dtable <- datatable(
    dat,
    rownames = TRUE,
    extensions = "Buttons",
    options = 
        list(
            dom = "Bfrtip",
            buttons = 
                list(
                    list(
                        extend = "copy",
                        text = paste0("Copy ", as.character(fa_i("dog")))
                    ),
                    list(
                        extend = "csv",
                        text = paste0("CSV ", as.character(fa_i("fish")))
                    )
                )
        )
    )

# add the 'fontawesome' HTML dependency:
deps <- dtable$dependencies
deps <- c(deps, list(fa_html_dependency()))
dtable$dependencies <- deps

dtable


The last step, adding the fontawesome HTML dependency, is not necessary in a Shiny app.
